# Assistance needed writing SQL queries using IF THEN statements

Tags: sql-server

I am learning SQL at school and am stumped on a particular query. We are using the AdventureWorks2014 DB, and the question is:
"The marketing department wants to know if the Road-650 bicycle has more than 10 styles currently available. Using the Product table, create a statement using IF THEN logic to trigger on whether there are more or less than 10 of Road-650 bicycle units available. Submit the statement and the result of the query."

I have located the ProductModelID of 30 for the bikes, and I can see there are 12 results, but I am having a difficult time even starting the query. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Here is as far as I have gotten so far, but the IF statement doesn't work and I get errors.

```
USE Adventureworks2014

SELECT 
    COUNT(ProductModelID) AS 'Styles' 
FROM 
    Production.Product
WHERE 
    ProductModelID = 30
GO

IF Styles >= 10
    PRINT 'More than 10 styles available'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Less than 10 styles available';
```

Comment: Perhaps it helps to describe the **structure of the database**? What tables are in it? How do these tables look like? ... How do you expect us to write you a query without that knowledge?

Comment: My apologies, I am new to this. This database is a sample database for SQL Server and has many many tables. This particular table is the Production.Product table, contains ProductID, Name, ProductNumber and several other columns, the only being particular to the Road-650 is the ProductModelID which is 30 for that model. I was hoping someone familiar with this sample database would be able to help out.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42894722/edit) your question.

Comment: Off topic because [SO help on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Some questions are still off-topic: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a blind man's help

if youre new, basically, IF ELSE statement is like this (everywhere)

IF (condition)

THEN (true statement)

ELSE (false statement)

END IF

try to google some before asking. people will appreciate your effort more than just randomly ask without researching.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the count to a variable:

```
USE Adventureworks2014

DECLARE @NumStyles INT

SELECT @NumStyles = COUNT(ProductModelID) AS 'Styles'
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductModelID = 30


IF @NumStyles >= 10 BEGIN
    PRINT 'More than 10 styles available'
END ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'Less than 10 styles available'
END
```

Or you could do this in the if statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM Production.Product 
            WHERE ProductModelID = 30 
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10) BEGIN
    PRINT 'More than 10 styles available'
END ELSE BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Less than 10 styles available'
END
```